# Android | Force onClick method on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application I have dynamic vertical boom menu. However menu is being opened only if user clicks boom menu button and I want to show it immidiately after activity is created. I searched for solution this this issue and found few but none of them worked. Heres my onCreate method :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_pik, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

        Category category1 = new Category();
        Category category2 = new Category();
        Category category3 = new Category();
        Category category4 = new Category();
        Category category5 = new Category();

        categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(category1);
        categories.add(category2);
        categories.add(category3);
        categories.add(category4);
        categories.add(category5);
        adapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories,getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        mScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mScrollView.scrollToPosition(2);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(2).itemView.callOnClick();
            }
        },1);

        mScrollView.setItemTransformer(new ScaleTransformer.Builder()
                .setMaxScale(1.05f)
                .setMinScale(0.8f)
                .setPivotX(Pivot.X.CENTER) // CENTER is a default one
                .setPivotY(Pivot.Y.BOTTOM) // CENTER is a default one
                .build();


        return view;
    }
```

This is my onBindViewHolder :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Category category = channelList.get(position);

        holder.menuButton.clearBuilders();
        holder.menuButton.setButtonEnum(ButtonEnum.SimpleCircle);
        holder.menuButton.setPiecePlaceEnum(PiecePlaceEnum.DOT_6_3);
        holder.menuButton.setButtonPlaceEnum(ButtonPlaceEnum.SC_6_3);
        holder.menuButton.setDotRadius(0);
        holder.menuButton.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_empty_icon));
        holder.menuButton.setNormalColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        holder.menuButton.setShadowEffect(false);


        for (int i = 0; i < holder.menuButton.getButtonPlaceEnum().buttonNumber(); i++) {
            holder.menuButton.addBuilder(new SimpleCircleButton.Builder()
                    .normalColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
                    .normalImageRes(R.drawable.logo_splash_screen)
                    .listener(new OnBMClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBoomButtonClick(int index) {
                            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), AddPikActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                        }
                    }));
        }

    }
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Hi! I am finding this hard to understand. Is this button a part of the menu which you are trying to open? Also can you share a screenshot of you have.

Comment: I've got vertical menu with 6 buttons. After clicking it opens the new menu - works similar to floating button. As you can see in the code I set up recycler view to position 2 and I want to open automatically menu from this position.